# How can I set a document as a DBref in Mongoose and still have access to the document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I set a DBref using the referenced document itself and still have access to the document as if it were populated on the parent object?

If I have a simple schema with a field setup as a dbref field:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  'title': String,
  '_author', { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users'}
});
var Post = mongoose.model('posts', PostSchema);

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  'name': String
});
Var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

If I try to do this:

```
var john = User.findOne({'name': 'john'});
var post = new Post({'title': 'My Post'});
post._author = john;

post.save(function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(post._author);
  }
});
```

The **post._author** property has a value of the author._id. I'd prefer to have the _author property have the value of the entire author document (similar to if I had performed a find query on the posts collection and populated the author object).

My only solution is to perform such a findOne query inside the save callback and ensure that I populate the author back in... this feels a bit off as I'm basically having to requery when I already have all the information.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of the [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) functionality of Mongoose.  In your example, you'd set `post._author = john._id` when creating the post, and then when querying the post collection you'd use code like this to populate `_author` with the full User object:

```
post.findOne({'title': 'My Post'}).populate('_author').exec(function (err, post) {
    // post._author contains a User model instance
});
```

Comment: Yes, this works very well when I am just retrieving the data, but after I've set the data do I then have to `findOne` as you describe? It seems a bit odd to have to issue a `find` query when I already have the required data.